# Why does the RECT of a window not change by resizing it through dragging the left/top edge of it?

Tags: winapi, gdi

The following is my WindowProc function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_SIZE:
            {

                break;
            }
        case WM_PAINT:
            {
                int height = 50;
                TCHAR buff[256] = { 0 };
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                SetMapMode(hdc, MM_TEXT);
                RECT windowSize;
                RECT logicExtent;
                GetWindowRect(hwnd, &windowSize);
                logicExtent = windowSize;
                DPtoLP(hdc, (LPPOINT)(&logicExtent), 2);
                memset(buff, 0, 256);
                _stprintf_s(buff, TEXT("TEXT MODE:Physical Extent=[%d, %d], Logical Extent=[%d,%d]"), windowSize.right, windowSize.bottom, logicExtent.right, logicExtent.bottom);
                TextOut(hdc,0, height * 0,buff, _tcslen(buff));
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
                break;
            }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I find a problem which really confuses me, that when I resize the window through dragging the right/bottom edge of it the values printed will change, while the values do not change when I resize the window by dragging the left/top edge of it. Could someone explain to me the reason?

Comment: Perhaps the bottom right point coordinates do not change. I would bet the width and length of the window gets updated.

Comment: HAHAHAHA... So stupid I was. I didn't realize it. Thank you.

Comment: Use `right - left` and `bottom - top` to calculate size from a `RECT` structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect) structure,

> right
>
> Specifies the x-coordinate of the lower-right corner of the rectangle.
>
> bottom
>
> Specifies the y-coordinate of the lower-right corner of the rectangle.

Dragging the left/top edge of windows does not change the coordinate of the lower-right corner of it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that GetWindowRect gets the position and size of the window (including the non-client area) *in screen coordinates*.  If you resize from the top-left corner, you'll see the left and top members of the RECT change.

GetClientRect gets the position and size of the client area *in client coordinates*.  By definition, the top-left corner of the client area is attached to client coordinate (0, 0).  So the client rectangle always has 0 for the left and top members and thus the right and bottom members will always equal the width and height.

---

There's probably some caveat that belongs here to warn about mirroring mode, which is a legacy(?) feature to make code written for left-to-right languages compatible with right-to-left languages.  I don't recall the details of how mirroring mode affects the various coordinate systems.